# color problem Epson XP215

Tags: epson, color-management

I just installed Epson XP 215. Printing plain black text works,only the CMYK colours are not lined up correctly: there is a vertical shift...

Can someone help me on fixing that problem?

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

For my Epson XP 231 for Ubuntu 16.04, I had a similar problem. I've [installed the open source driver](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-XP-200_Series) and it was fixed!